# Getting to block from layout xml issue

Tags: magento-1, xml

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="accordion">
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_view_subscription" name="myname" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

This my Block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Subscription extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo 1; exit();
    }
}
```

this is my module xml from etc folder:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </helpers>
</global>
```

My question is: why do I not get the `echo 1 ; exit () ;` ?

update [image]

Comment: My question: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Just adding another custom grid, like recent orders

Comment: i think you are trying to add tab here in customer gird?

Comment: yes , indeed :). Did I do smth wrong at this point ?

Comment: add the answer kindly check and feedback me

Answer (score 0):

in layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
        <adminhtml_customer_edit>
            <reference name="customer_info_tabs">
                <action method="addTab">
                    <name>younameherer</name>
                    <block>mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_view_subscription</block>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </adminhtml_customer_edit>
    </layout>
```

your block code will be

```
<?php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Subscription extends Mage_Core_Block_Template implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setTemplate('customfields/content.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the label used for the tab relating to this block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Extra FIelds');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the title used by this tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Extra FIelds');
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether to display the tab
     * Add logic here to decide whether you want the tab to display
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the tab being hidden
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * AJAX TAB's
     * If you want to use an AJAX tab, uncomment the following functions
     * Please note that you will need to setup a controller to recieve
     * the tab content request
     *
     */
    /**
     * Retrieve the class name of the tab
     * Return 'ajax' here if you want the tab to be loaded via Ajax
     *
     * return string
     */
#   public function getTabClass()
#   {
#       return 'my-custom-tab';
#   }

    /**
     * Determine whether to generate content on load or via AJAX
     * If true, the tab's content won't be loaded until the tab is clicked
     * You will need to setup a controller to handle the tab request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
#   public function getSkipGenerateContent()
#   {
#       return false;
#   }

    /**
     * Retrieve the URL used to load the tab content
     * Return the URL here used to load the content by Ajax 
     * see self::getSkipGenerateContent & self::getTabClass
     *
     * @return string
     */
#   public function getTabUrl()
#   {
#       return null;
#   }
}
```

Comment: srry, but this add a tab in the left menu, right , i want to add tab which contains a grid la recent order. If you check my img.  Thx a lot for the help